# how to changed font size that table to fit div

Tags: javascript, html, web

I have html

```
<div style="width: 1000px;">
  <table >
  ...
  </table>
</div>
```

Table is very large and not all fields fit into div. How to automatically reduce the text to the entire table is placed in a div?

Comment: css: font-size? Or give the table rows an id and style width accordingly.

Comment: in different browsers with different size fonts, if use just the font-size while in use css style for specific browser?

Comment: I don't think you'd need to style for specific browsers if you use % or em. I've recently read a very interesting article, I'll post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question right, you're trying to fit text into a table and change font size according to the table size. This would require working with em or %.

There's a great article on [A List Apart.](http://alistapart.com/article/howtosizetextincss) You should check that out.

Also; add a [Stylesheet Reset](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) to ensure everything looks the same in different browsers.

Comment: I reduced the size with % but still the font size in all browsers display differently.

Comment: Have you used a CSS Style Reset to ensure browser consistency?